# Simple Joining in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I am currently trying to join table 1 and table 2 to get the third table 3 but I am having trouble. The A and B are similar for each. They can be linked by `Company_ID`.

[image]

Comment: If you're having trouble, it would be helpful if you explained what sort of trouble you're having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what exactly the problem is, but here's the syntax for performing a simple join on `company_id` and assuming you only want `a` and `b` once:

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, c, d, e, f
FROM   t1
JOIN   t2 ON t1.company_id = t2.company_id
```